# C - Writing multi-lined txt in memory

Tags: malloc

I'm working in PUTTY, using C. I have a .txt file with the data of multiple users. For example, a line looks like: "SSNumber, Name, PhoneNumber, Class, Age(...)". There's only one line per user. I want to write it in a shared memory location with malloc. But I'll have to change one of the fields later on. How can I do this? Do I need to read it line by line, anyway? It's very confusing.
Thanks!
Is this enough?

```c
if (fp != NULL) {
      /* Vai ao fim do ficheiro. */
      if (fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END) == 0) {
          long bufsize = ftell(fp);
          if (bufsize == -1) { /* Error */ }
          source = malloc(sizeof(char) * (bufsize + 1));
          if (fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET) == 0) { /* Error */ }
          size_t newLen = fread(source, sizeof(char), bufsize, fp);
          if (newLen == 0) {
              fputs("Error reading file", stderr);
          } else {
              source[++newLen] = '\0'; /* Just to be safe. */
          }
      }
      fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Oh boy, SSNs? Are you using a database of any kind?

Comment: No. We create a txt file with the data in the format i said. "SSNumber, Name, PhoneNumber, Class, Age(...)" . A .sh script generates it, but that's not the case. It has more than 100 lines  - users. 
The .c file which i'm trying to create will read that .txt, allocate the user's fields in memory, and then, later on , i will have to update/refresh some of them. Hope i was clear with this explanation.

Comment: Side note: `fseek(...) == 0` is not an error (on the contrary)!!!

Comment: Side note #2: `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition!

Comment: Side note #3: PUTTY is an ssh client - just a way of communicating with another computer over the 'net.  Telling us that you are "in PUTTY" tells us nothing useful.  Rather, we may need to know details of the computer you have used PUTTY to connect to -- what operating system, what CPU, how old it is, that sort of thing.